# C++ Multithreaded TCP Server Issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm writing a simple TCP server. The model that I though of is the server accepting client connections in the main thread and handing them over to another thread so that server can listen for connections again. The relevant parts of the code that I used are posted below:

Accepting connections:

```
void startServer () {

    int serverSideSocket = 0;
    int clientSideSocket = 0;

    serverSideSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (serverSideSocket < 0) {
        error("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    clientAddressLength = sizeof(clientAddress);
    memset((char *) &serverAddress, 0, sizeof(serverAddress));
    memset((char *) &clientAddress, 0, clientAddressLength);

    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(32000);

    if (bind(serverSideSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) {
        error("ERROR on binding");
        exit(1);
    }      

    listen(serverSideSocket, SOMAXCONN);

    while(true) {
        clientSideSocket = accept(serverSideSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress, &clientAddressLength);

    if (clientSideSocket < 0)
            error("ERROR on accept");

        processingThreadGroup->create_thread(boost::bind(process, clientSideSocket, this));
    }

}
```

Here, the processingThreadGroup is a boost::thread_group instance. In the process method:

```
void process (int clientSideSocket, DataCollector* collector) {

int numberOfCharactersRead = 0;
string buffer;

do {
      char msgBuffer[1000];
      numberOfCharactersRead = recv(clientSideSocket, msgBuffer, (1000 - 1), 0);
      if (numberOfCharactersRead < 0) {
          //display error
          close(clientSideSocket);
      }
      else if (numberOfCharactersRead == 0)
          close(clientSideSocket);
      else {
          printf("%s", msgBuffer);
          memset(msgBuffer, 0, 1000);
      }
   } while (numberOfCharactersRead > 0); 
}
```

However, when I debug the code, I saw that when the processing thread is invoked, the main thread is not accepting connections anymore. The data is read inside the process() method only. The main thread seem to be not running anymore. What is the issue with the approach I took and any suggestions to correct it?

EDIT: I think I found the issue here, and have updated it as an answer. Will not accept it since I answered my own question. Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: Maybe your main thread is not receiving processor time for some reason. Try to determine where your main thread is stuck. Set breakpoint in `process` where you are feeling the main thread is frozen and take a look at main thread execution point.

Comment: your approach is fine... what error are you getting from second+ call in accept?  it's possible that your second+ iteration has clientAddress and clientAddressLength with something unexpected... you probably should initialize them in the top of the while(true) loop just before accept anyway...

Comment: 'printf("%s", msgBuffer);' seems a bit dubious the first time round, since no memset(), in general, though, why an attempted printf of a unterminated string could stuff your accept() thread, I don't know.  Still...

Comment: @Rost Yeah - debugging 101. What happens if you just close the client socket at the top of 'process' and return?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for all the suggestions. I put some debug points in the main loop, however seems like that only the spawned thread is running. The main thread debug points are not hit after the first time. All the subsequent data are received through the first connection accepted. 
However, if I close the client socket after printing the received data, then the next connection is again directed to another thread by the main thread. I'm clueless why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: what platform is this?  are you code-generating and linking with multi-threaded libraries?

Comment: This is in ubuntu.  I wrote the server code. There is a generated part as well for some thrift files, but not in the server part. I'm using netbeans C++ IDE and am linking with the boost libraries through the IDE.

Comment: Can you show us what the create_thread function does? Is that part of boost? Is the pool size 1? Does it block if no threads are available?

Comment: @grieve: yes, create_thread is a part of boost. I have not specified a size for the thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

Think I found the issue. I was using this as a server to accept syslog messages. The code I use for the syslog message generator is as follows:

```
openlog ("MyProgram", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL0);
cout << "opened the log" << endl;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) 
{
    syslog (LOG_INFO, "Program started by User %d \n", getuid ());
    syslog (LOG_WARNING, "Beware of the WARNING! \n");
    syslog (LOG_ERR, "fatal ERROR! \n");
}   
closelog ();
cout << "closed the log" << endl;
```

and I use an entry in the rsyslog.conf file to direct all syslog LOG_LOCAL0 application traffic to be sent to the relevant TCP port where the server is listening. Somehow, syslog allows only one connection to be made, not multiple connections. Therefore, it only used one connection in a single thread. If that connection was closed, a new connection is craeted.

I checked with a normal tcp client. That works fine, with multiple threads being spawned for each connection accepted.